# How can I make audio applications use 44.1kHz as the default sample rate, Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: sound, alsa, kodi, 21.10, audio-player

Its all change now with pipewire.

I have a USB-attached DAC which shows the current sample rate (but not the bit depth) and I'm currently using Kodi - but it is choosing to access the DAC at 48kHz so it must be resampling my CDs - I want to stop it doing that.

Ideally I'd be happy to access at 32le depth and 44.1kHz.

Comment: Do you use Pulseaudio? Are you sure the DAC supports 44.1kHz?

Comment: No pulseaudio is not installed.  I have now disabled pipewire and added a plug in .asoundrc that forces 32LE at 44100.   The computer is a dedicated music player.  It seems to be behaving now.